# What is transition function of scheme theoretic vector bundle ??

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, schemes, affine-varieties, algebraic-vector-bundles

Let X be a scheme X and $\mathscr{F}$ be a locally free sheaf of rank $n$ over $X$.
I want to consider a vector bundle over an algebraic variety $X$ , that is , 
 the relative spec over $X$ of symmetric algebra of $\mathscr{F}$ ; $V=Spec(Sym \mathscr{F})$.
We write $\rho$ as the natural morphism $V \longrightarrow X$.

Can you define '' transition function of $\rho:V \longrightarrow X$ '' $??$
If it is possible to define that , how can you do it $??$

Comment: Choose local trivializations for $\mathcal{F}$, the transition functions for those will give you transition functions for $V$.

Comment: Can you explain it in detail ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Total space of a finite rank locally free sheaf, Vakil's 17.1.4 & 17.1.G](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707383/total-space-of-a-finite-rank-locally-free-sheaf-vakils-17-1-4-17-1-g)